# How do i add a dropdown data binding to an API Json datatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the datatable component. I want to add a dynamic dropdown to display the Gender, such that on the first page load, the API call uses the default parameters to get all records..

```
function Beneficiary() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/bhcpf?query={}&limit=0&skip=0"
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      const item = result.data;

      setTimeout(() => {
        setPerson(item);
        dispatch(setPersonDetails(item[0]));
        setLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
    };
    getData();
  }, [dispatch]);


  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TopWrapper>
        <IconButton onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
          <ArrowBackIcon />
        </IconButton>
        
      </TopWrapper>


      <MiddleWrapper>
        <h1> Beneficiaries </h1>

        <SearchWrapper>
          
              //add dropdown

        </SearchWrapper>

      </MiddleWrapper>

      <BottomWrapper>
        {loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <Table
            cellSpacing="40"
            cellPadding="20"
            striped
            bordered
            hover
            responsive
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Enrollment ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>LGA</th>
                <th>WARD</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {person
                .map((record) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={record.id}>
                      <td>{record.enrollment_id}</td>

                      <td>
                        {" "}
                        <Link
                          onClick={() => dispatch(setPersonDetails(record))}
                        >
                          {record.full_name}
                        </Link>
                      </td>
                      <td>{record.gender}</td>
                      <td>{record.lga}</td>
                      <td> {record.ward} </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        )}
      </BottomWrapper>
      
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Beneficiary;
```

However, when the dropdown changes, an event should trigger a fresh call to the API using the selected value as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have one extra state like

```
const [selectedGender,setSelectedGender] = useState("Female"); //any default value of your choice
```

place the dropdown in your desired location

```
<select id="gender" value="Female" onChange={(e)=>setSelectedGender(e.target.value)>
 <option value="Male">Male</option>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
 <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

now modify your code to render the data based on the user's choice of gender by modifying your useEffect code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://pshs3.herokuapp.com/bhcpf?query={}&limit=0&skip=0&gender=${selectedGender}`
      );
      const result = await response.json();
      const item = result.data;

      setTimeout(() => {
        setPerson(item);
        dispatch(setPersonDetails(item[0]));
        setLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
    };
    getData();
  }, [dispatch,selectedGender]);
```

The above code fetches you the JSON data with gender as female for the first time and from the next time fetches the json data based on the user's choice of gender.

Comment: Thank you krishnakirit04. It actually helped. Much appreciated.

Comment: glad to help, if it answered your question make it the accepted solution. Cheers!!